# Jquery .post() method problem

Tags: jquery, post, methods

I have the following Jquery function that should post  memberID as a variable.And I want to catch it in my add_comment.php file with   `$memberID = $_REQUEST['memberID']` but it returns null.

```
$('a.comment').die("click").live("click", function(e){

        var getpID =  $(this).parent().attr('id').replace('commentBox-','');    
        var comment_text = $("#commentMark-"+getpID).val();


        if(comment_text != "Write a comment...")
        {
            $.post("lib/actions/add_comment.php?comment_text="
                      +comment_text+"&post_id="+getpID,{ memberID : 5 

            }, function(response){

                $('#CommentPosted'+getpID).append($(response).fadeIn('slow'));
                $("#commentMark-"+getpID).val("Write a comment...");                    
            });
        }

    });
```

Comment: Can you try by escaping the 'comment_text'?

Answer (score 0):

You need to [URL-encode (with `encodeURIComponent`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) `comment_text`, but why aren't you just sending that in the POST data?

Can't you do:

```
$.post("lib/actions/add_comment.php", {
    comment_text: comment_text,
    post_id: getpID,
    memberID: 5
}, function (response) { //etc.
```

?